# How to add Special characters to the file name in this case

Tags: java

Before Storing a file i am checking if the file name already exists (to prevent overriding)

For this i am using the following code

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;


public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String imagename = checkImage("big_buck_bunny.mp4");
        System.out.println(imagename);
    }

    public static String checkImage(String image_name) {
        String newimage = "";
        ArrayList<String> image_nameslist = new ArrayList<String>();
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Public\\Videos\\Sample Videos\\");
        File[] files = file.listFiles();
        for (File f : files) {
            image_nameslist.add(f.getName());
        }
        long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (image_nameslist.contains(image_name)) {
            Random randomGenerator = new Random();
            int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(100);
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)\\.(.*?)").matcher(image_name);
            if (matcher.matches()) { // <== test input filename is OK?
                newimage = String.format("%s_%d.%s", matcher.group(1),randomInt, matcher.group(2));
            }
        }
        else {
            newimage = image_name;
        }
        return newimage;
    }
}
```

And the output i get is

```
big_buck_bunny_50.mp4
```

In place of randomInt in the above code , is it possible to add some special characters @ before and after so that the output looks like\

```
big_buck_bunny_@50@.mp4
```

Comment: Have you tried it? Should not be a problem if OS accepts it.

Comment: I think you should better not check the file name like that. It will fail in cases where different filenames refer to the same file, for example with case insensitive filesystems. Better create a `File` object abd check using the `exists()` method. Also in your code there is no guarantee that `newimage` does not already exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just form a string with special characters using your random integer, and then include it in the call to `String.format()`.  The only change I made to your call was to replace `%d` with `%s` and to use the random string instead of the random integer.

```
String randStr = "@" + String.valueOf(randomInt) + "@";
newimage = String.format("%s_%s.%s", matcher.group(1), randStr, matcher.group(2));
```

But, are you sure that your OS accepts/recommends such file names?